# How can i get code for this html output without css attributes?

Tags: html, web, google-web-designer

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kcfB.png) I need to make table like this but I don't know how to. i tried different ways  hut I don't know how to adjust table spacing in html. (without css attributes)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you clearly, You can just use [colspan](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/html-colspan-attribute/) and [rowspan](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/html-rowspan-attribute/), See this snippet below

```html
<table border="black">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">Title</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td rowspan="3">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="">
  </td>
  <td>
    Label 1
  </td>
  <td>
    Description
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
    Label 1
  </td>
  <td>
    Description
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
    Label 1
  </td>
  <td>
    Description
  </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<table border="1" cellspacing="10">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">Title</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td rowspan="3">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="">
  </td>
  <td>
    Label 1
  </td>
  <td>
    Description
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
    Label 1
  </td>
  <td>
    Description
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
    Label 1
  </td>
  <td>
    Description
  </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```